# Calculating the number of combinations given a ruleset

Tags: combinations

Using the following table as an example for this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68kmq.jpg)

The rules are:

1. The left column is unchanging,         each column 1 section (A, B, C, D)
   takes up 3 rows while each column            2 section only takes up 1
2. Only rows 6-9 can be used in column  2
3. A column 2 section cannot share a row with its column 2 pair (i.e    column 2 section C can only be in
   row 6)
4. Column 2 can have a maximum of 2 sections in its row (you could have C and A in the same row but not C A and D)

How many combinations are possible for column 2?

(If an analogy for this would help, imagine there’s 4 guards. Column 1 is guard shift times and column 2 is their lunch breaks, you couldn’t have a lunch break while guarding)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.